# How to change the default startup folder in Termux?

Tags: android, terminal, dropbox, termux

Currently I've been using the Termux terminal on Android Samsung phone. So basicly every time i want to go to my Dropbox folder via terminal i need to cd into the "home/storage/shared/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/ u1407419/scratch/org " directory, which is not very time effective. Is there a way to change the default Termux folder, so that each time Termux is opened it automaticly jumps to the folder mentioned ? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Instead of changing the default Termux folder which is quite a hectic and unworthy process, a quick workaround would be that you try this:

1. Edit the bash.bashrc file located here
   `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/bash.bashrc` using nano or any other text editor...

   → Command : `nano /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. And append this line to the end of the file...

→Append : `cd ~/storage/shared/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/ u1407419/scratch/org`

3. Restart your terminal and you will find that it always opens up in your desired directory!